# BeanDefinitionStoreException exception since trying to switch app to javaconfig from xml config

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-java-config

I am running into some configuration issue since trying **to switch to javaconfig from xml config**.

Here is the problematic configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@Profile({ "default", "cloud" })
public class DataConfiguration {

    @Value("${database.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${database.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${database.validationQuery}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1800000);
        dataSource.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1800000);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(5);
        dataSource.setLogAbandoned(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePersistence persistenceProvider() {
        return new HibernatePersistence();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory", destroyMethod = "close")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.bignibou.domain");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(persistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesMap());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public Map<String, String> propertiesMap() {
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
        return propertiesMap;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

}
```

Here is the **exception** I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static javax.persistence.EntityManager org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.initProxyClassLoader(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:151)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.<init>(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:143)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:96)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 122 more
```

It seems **there's an issue with the entityManagerFactory config**... What I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using the `entityManagerFactory()` method anywhere in your java configuration, you can instead return the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` object.

The `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is both an `InitializingBean` and a `FactoryBean`. These are special interfaces that Spring can use to initialize a bean and then add it to the context.

You could therefore change your method to

```
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory", destroyMethod = "close")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.bignibou.domain");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(persistenceProvider());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesMap());
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

Spring will take care of calling `afterPropertiesSet()` and `getObject()` on the object returned by the method and adding the created `EntityManagerFactory` bean to the context.

[This  is detailed in the IoC chapter of the Spring documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

Comment: Sotirios, your solution works fine but it should reveal the hidden problem a bit more. balteo has pointed out the problem: the initialisation code was missing. In your solution Spring calls afterPropertiesSet on the factory bean on its own. This is why your solution works.

Comment: @rwoo It's all there in the last 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 4):

adding the following line sorted the issue:

```
entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesMap());
entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();//NOTICE HERE!!!
return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks, balteo! I tend to forget this bit again and again. Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean should generate a meaning error message if getObject() is called but afterPropertiesSet() is not called yet.